# JCE pro adding space between < & ! while commenting code in <Style> tag in editor

Tags: editor, joomla3.0, jce

I just updated the JCE extension to JCE Pro(version - 2.9.10) in Joomla 3.9.27.
Now, in the article content in Joomla at the admin panel, I am adding the style tag with the  comment like below

```
<style>
<!--
.wrapper {
 display:block;
 padding: 10px;
}
-->
</style>
```

Now when I switch the editor to the Code tab then it adds the space between < & ! like below

```
<style>
< !--
.wrapper {
 display:block;
 padding: 10px;
}
-->
</style>
```

before updating to the JCE pro it worked fine.

Please check the below image for more details.

**Editor tab**

[image: In the editor tab]

**Code tab**
[image: In the Code Tab]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment code in CSS, you wrap it inside `/*  */` marks, eg

```
<style>
/*
 .wrapper {
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
*/
</style>
```

You've unintentionally used the HTML comment marks `<!--  -->`